# microcanonical distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics

In the book 'Statistical Physics' by Daijiro Yoshioka, the author states without proof that *almost all microscopic states will be realised as the state of the system changes temporally*. I'm not entirely certain I managed to prove this using the Borel-Cantelli theorem as follows:

1. We consider a system of solid, liquid, or gas enclosed by an adiabatic wall.
2. We assume fixed Volume($V$),fixed number of molecules ($N$), and fixed but total energy($E$) with uncertainty $\delta E$.
3. The total number of microscopic states allowed under the macroscopic constraints is given by

$$W=W(E,\delta E,V,N) \tag{1}$$
 Assuming that each micro-state is realised with equal probability, we have for any micro-state $m_i$:

$$ P(m_i | t_n) = \frac{1}{W} \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(m_i | t_n)=\infty \tag{2}$$

where I assume that the total number of micro-states is finite. We can then show using the Borel-Cantelli theorem that for any $m_i$, $E_n=\{m_i | t_n\}$ occurs infinitely often.

**Note 1**: There's something that bothers me about my proof. Somehow it assumes that the probability of transition between any two states,no matter how different, is always the same. For this reason, I now think that this proof might require more than the Borel-Cantelli theorem and that the 'equal probability' assumption might not hold for state transitions. It seems reasonable that some transitions would be more likely than others. Maybe I can use Borel-Cantelli for 'large-enough' time intervals. But, this would need careful justification as well.

**Note 2**: I think it might be helpful to use an integrable variant of the Borel-Cantelli theorem: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258389/integrable-version-of-the-borel-cantelli-theorem

Comment: What is $t_n$? Also, how does showing that $E_n$ occurs infinitely often prove the statement in your first sentence?